# How to reset the view state of a ViewHolder in ViewPager2, once it is not visible anymore?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-viewpager2

I'm using a `ViewPager2` and a `ListAdapter` to scroll horizontally through `Recycler.ViewHolder` items, showing one item at a time. Each can be scrolled vertically when the content doesn't fit on the screen.

I would like to reset the scroll state of the items once they are not visible anymore, because the view holder is likely to be reused for another item, and because it's tidier.

I know how to reset the scroll state in the `ViewHolder`, but *where* can I put this code?

I first thought it could be in the fragment hosting the `ViewPager2`, where I could register a callback `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback` with the viewpager:

```
private var lastPosition = -1
private var callback = object: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        if (lastPosition >= 0) {
            // reset scroll here
            val v: MyViewHolder = ???(position)
            v.resetScrollState()
        }
        lastPosition = position
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewpager = binding.itemPager
    viewpager.adapter = [...]
    viewpager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(callback)
}
```

(where `binding.itemPager` points to the `ViewPager2`)

But I don't know how to easily get to the view holder, except by storing it (in an collection for ex.) so I can retrieve it from `position`. Then I would still have to correctly set `lastPosition` for the first time but it's secondary.

**My question**:
Is there any way to

- set a listener to a change of page, with access to the view holder?
- or alternatively, retrieve the view holder in function of `position`?

Or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it eventually.

For a given `lastPosition`, the view holder can be obtained with:

```
(viewpager.get(0) as RecyclerView).findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastPosition)
    as? MyViewHolder
```

So the callback becomes:

```
private var callback = object: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        if (lastPosition >= 0) {
            // reset scroll here
            val holder = (viewpager.get(0) as RecyclerView).findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(lastPosition) as? TodoEventAdapter.MyViewHolder
            if (holder != null)
                holder.resetScroll()
        }
        lastPosition = position
    }
}
```

I can set the initial value of `lastPosition` and register the callback, for example in the fragment code with `ViewPager2.currentItem`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewpager = binding.itemPager
    [...]
    lastPosition = viewpager.currentItem
    viewpager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(callback)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    [...]
    viewpager.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(callback)
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

Where `binding.itemPager` uses viewBinding, and corresponds to the ViewPager2 instance of the layout.

Note that the first position to show is likely to come from a parameter, for example an activity that needs to display a specific item at a starting position. The initial value of `lastPosition` may be obtained from this parameter, or from the `ViewPager2.currentItem` value once/if it has been set, as shown above.